# Setting the output voltage of MAX8792

Tags: pwm, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, step-down

I'm interested in using [MAX8792](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX8792.pdf) in order to create 1.8V primary voltage for Tiger Lake UP3 intel CPU.

I didn't find any formula that relates to the output resistor divider in order to set the output voltage.

also, in Maxim Integrated website, MAX8792 wasn't available for simulation (or creating design based on my specs), how can I use the datasheet to decide what conductor I need for 3A output?

the specs are: Vin = 12V, Vout = 1.8V, Maximum Output Current: 3A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the pin descriptions on page 10 of the datasheet:

[image]

So you can use a voltage divider with REF to establish 1.8V on REFIN and then connect the output of the converter to FB.

The application circuit on page 11 shows an example of this:

[image]

When the MOSFET is OFF, the voltage at REFIN is about 1.5V and when ON around 1.05V.

Answer (score 1):

The internal reference is 2V, so to get output voltage of 1.8V you need to connect FB directly to the output and use either a precision external reference or a resistive divider to apply 1.8V to REFIN.

Per the datasheet, Pin Description table:

FB

Feed back Voltage-Sense Connection. **Connect directly to the positive terminal of the output capacitors for output voltages less than 2V as shown in Figure 1.** For fixed-output voltages greater than 2V, connect REFIN to REF and use a resistive divider to set the output voltage (Figure 4) . FB senses the output voltage to determine the on-time for the high-side switching MOSFET.

REFIN

External Reference Input. **REFIN sets the feedback regulation voltage (VFB = VREFIN) of the MAX8792** using the resistor-divider connected between REF and GND. The MAX8792 includes an internal window comparator to detect REFIN voltage transitions, allowing the controller to blank PGOOD and the fault protection.

*(Disclosure: I am an applications engineer at Maxim Integrated)*